# Sharepoint 2010 with Access Query

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I am unable to determine if the following is possible:

Create queries in Access

Export as a list to a SharePoint 2010 list

Each time the list is accessed within SharePoint, it executes the query and brings back up to date information.

Any information would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: [Synchronize a SharePoint 2010 list with Access 2010](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Synchronize-a-SharePoint-2010-list-with-Access-2010-975BFB97-C799-4FCE-B7CC-3DB3B397F116).

Comment: I read that, it doesn't answer my question.  It involves linked tables...

Comment: Then the answer is "no".  The queries can only be run within Access. If you are simply :"exporting" the Access table to a SharePoint list then all you have is a copy of the data.  Yet, the best answer would be to simply create a test case to see if it does what you want within your specific environment (especially if the SP instance is hosted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work, the list you produce as an export of your query is static and has no links to database tables that originated the data.  To accomplish this task you will need to look at creating an external list in SharePoint by utilizing the business data catalog.  This allows you to point SharePoint directly at database tables.  I have linked the walkthrough for doing this below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231515.aspx

Generally speaking, you'd want to use SQL Server or another supported SQL engine that is network accessible to house this data.  Access isn't ideal.